# Basename like string manipulation when using pipes

Tags: linux, string, bash, echo

## Hello and thank you in advance for your answers.

When I use the following code, I get output such as:

```
  /home/pony/IOSO/test/A
  /home/pony/IOSO/test/B


FILE=last.cfg
DIR=$(realpath "$2") #or something else    
grep $DIR $FILE | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq # | basename does not work
```

How do I make my pipe work with basename or something like this:

```
$ s=/the/path/foo.txt
$ echo ${s##*/}
foo.txt
```

Comment: try `grep $DIR $FILE | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq | sed 's~.*/~~'`

Comment: That did it! Thanks. Not sure how to select you as the correct answer since I just joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `awk` so that you can avoid the unecessary usage of `grep` `awk` and `sed` sequance

The correct method can be

```
awk -v dir="$DIR" -F"/" '$0 ~ dir{print $NF}'
```

**Test**

```
$ DIR="/home/pony/IOSO/test"

$ cat input
/home/pony/IOSO/test/A
/home/pony/IOSO/test/B
/home/test/test

$ awk -v dir="$DIR" -F"/" '$0 ~ dir{print $NF}' input
A
B
```

**What it does**

- `-v dir="$DIR"` creates an `awk` variable with the value of shell variable `DIR`
- `-F"/"` set the field delimiter as the `/`. This is done as in input file the directories are separated by `/` and we need to get the last field, filename.
- `'$0 ~ dir` checks for each input line if it matches the pattern in variable `dir`
- `print $NF` print the last field, here the the filename. `NF` stands for number of fields.

Comment: Your solution might be much faster, but I'd like to avoid sequences of code I do not yet fully understand. You've definitely made me skim through the awk manpage this weekend.

Comment: @user3473750 I have added a small description for you. Hope it helps you now :)

Comment: @user3473750 It is the input file name which goes at the argument to `awk` at the very end. Replace `input` in the answer with `$FILE`. Like `awk -v dir="$DIR" -F"/" '$0 ~ dir{print $NF}' $FILE`

Comment: Well, thank you very much for teaching me something new. But since the first answer is closer to what we are being taught at school I'll choose that one, if only to avoid unnecessary questions when talking about my "project'.  I hate it how they call any silly homework a project now, but that's beside the point.

Comment: @user3473750 how this will do sorting?

Comment: @user3473750 You are welcome :). You can write that to please the teacher ;). But do keep in mind that there are different ways of doings things in linux some of which may be very cryptic and short. Do take time to explore and learn and use them. All the best!!

Comment: @AvinashRaj The problem is not with the `sort`. Op already knows that piping the result to `sort` command would do that. But the real question is how to match and extract the fields from input file. The answer just shows how it can differently aproached using `awk` alone

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `uniq` command's output to a sed command like below to remove all the characters upto the last `/` symbol.

```
grep $DIR $FILE | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort | uniq | sed 's~.*/~~'
```